# JSON.stringify won't work on JSON Object where properties are created with Object.defineproperty

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I'm currently writing a web scraping discord bot and want to implement the logic. I create the final Object it also has all properties that i set but when i try to console.log(totalData) it returns {}

same result when i do console.log(JSON.stringify(totalData)) => {}

i have also tried it with console.dir(), console.table()

The code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

let url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/";

async function scrapeAllByCountry(page, country){
   const totalData = {}
   let endPosition;

   // XPath to the data
   allData = ["/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[6]/div[1]/div/table/tbody[1]"]
   headerData = ["Country", "Total Cases", "New Cases", "Total Deaths", "New Deaths", "Total Recovered", "New recovered", "Active Cases", "Serious, Critical", "Total Cases/1M pop", "Deaths/1M pop", "Total Tests", "Tests/1M pop", "Population"]

   // scraping the data
   var element = await page.waitForXPath(allData[0])
   let allTableData = await page.evaluate(element => element.textContent, element)

   allTableData = allTableData.toLowerCase()
   // replacing comma with nothing so numbers return false when i call isNaN()
   allTableData = allTableData.replaceAll(",", "")

   // searches for the country in the string and saves it into positionCountry
   let positionCountry = allTableData.search(country.toLowerCase())
   // Adds 150 more chars so the full Data is in it
   let data = allTableData.substring(positionCountry, positionCountry + 150)
   // creates array for each row
   tempDataArray = data.split("\n");

   // searches for the next NAN in the array and sets the end position
   for(let i = 0; i < tempDataArray.length; i++){
      // if the current element is a number do nothing if it is a NaN set endPosition and exit
      if(isNaN(tempDataArray[i]) & i != 0){
         endPosition = i
         break;
      }
   }

   // create new Array with endposition
   let filteredArray = [];
   for(let i = 0; i < endPosition; i++){
      filteredArray.push(tempDataArray[i])
   }

   // Merge both Arrays into Object
   for(let i = 0; i < filteredArray.length; i++){
      // sets the header with a value on the totalDataObject
      Object.defineProperty(totalData, headerData[i], {
         value: filteredArray[i],
         writable: false
      })
      // here it confirms that it has all Properties
      console.log(totalData.hasOwnProperty(headerData[i]))
   }

   console.log(JSON.stringify(totalData)) // outputs {}

   return totalData
}

async function main(){
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({})
   const page = await browser.newPage()

   await page.goto(url)   
   
   let result = await scrapeAllByCountry(page, "Germany")
   console.log(JSON.stringify(result)) // also returns {}
   console.log(result.hasOwnProperty("Country"))

   browser.close()

} 

main();
```

Comment: [`Object.defineProperty`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#description): _“`enumerable`: `true` if and only if this property shows up during enumeration of the properties on the corresponding object. **Defaults to `false`.**”_. [`JSON.stringify`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description): _“All the other `Object` instances […] will have **only their enumerable properties serialized**.”_

Comment: Why not simply `totalData[headerData[i]] = filteredArray[i];` and `Object.freeze(totalData);`?

Comment: Thank you both methods worked i didn't know that you can write Object[<property>] = ...;